# JAVA TCP Client-Server connection

Tags: java, tcpclient, tcpserver

When I run this program the Client class prompts the user to enter a command, and that command should go to the Server class and open a file and read each line of that file and return the byte length back to the Client class to be displayed.

Unfortunately once i enter the command, nothing happens &  Not sure why.

TCP Client Class

```
package TcpClient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.*;

public class TcpClient {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String temp;
    String displayBytes;
    try {
      //create input stream
      BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      //create client socket, connect to server
      Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost",5555);
      //create output stream attached to socket
      DataOutputStream outToServer =
      new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

      System.out.print("Command : ");

      //create input stream attached to socket
      BufferedReader inFromServer =
      new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

      temp = inFromUser.readLine();

      //send line to server
      outToServer.writeBytes(temp);

      //read line from server
      //displayBytes = inFromServer.readLine();

      while((displayBytes = inFromServer.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.print(displayBytes);
      }
      //clientSocket.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
    }
  }
}
```

TCP Server Class

```
package TcpServer;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class TcpServer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // The name of the file to open.
    String fileName = "input.txt";
    // This will reference one line at a time
    String line = null;
    String holder=null;
    String clientWord;
    int bytNumber;

    try {
      //create welcoming socket at port 5555
      ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(5555);
      //wait, on welcoming socket for contact by client
      Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
      //create input stream, attached to socket
      BufferedReader inFromClient = 
      new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
      //create output stream, attached to socket
      DataOutputStream outToClient =
      new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
      //read in line from socket
      clientWord = inFromClient.readLine();

      if(clientWord.equals("query")) {
        try {
          // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
          FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);

          // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
          BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

          while((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            bytNumber = line.getBytes().length;
            holder=Integer.toString(bytNumber);
            //pr.println(bytNumber);//only printing first line not going until eof
            outToClient.writeBytes(holder);
            // line = buffer.readLine();
            // pr.flush();
          }   

          // Always close files.
          buffer.close();         
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
          System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + fileName + "'");
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
          System.out.println ("Error reading file '" + fileName + "'");
          // Or we could just do this: 
          // ex.printStackTrace();
        }
      }// end if statement
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You would start by **not** ignoring exceptions in your client class. You see, ignoring error messages isnt exactly a good way of debugging ...

Comment: The only message I get is a warning to close clientSocket but when i did that I still get the same output.

Comment: There can be various problems, like not properly closing sockets here or there, or connectivity issues, ... so, hint: try to run things in a debugger. Add print statements to see what is going on; and maybe first of all: read step by step tutorials (like http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html ) that guide you through the whole process of client/server communication.

Comment: @n00bie1221 How ironic that one of your catch blocks contains the comment "or we could just do this: ex.printStackTrace();" yet you choose **not** to do it, which is the worst mistake in the code you've shown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you to only `DataOutputStream` and `DataInputStream` in both sides and to not use `BufferedInputStream`.
The slightly modified code below is able to correctly send the message from the client to the server. Now you can easily make it work for what you want to achieve.

**Server**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;



public class TcpServer {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // The name of the file to open.
    String fileName = "input.txt";
    // This will reference one line at a time
    String line = null;
    String holder=null;
    String clientWord;
    int bytNumber;

    try
    {
        //create welcoming socket at port 5555
        ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(5555);
        //wait, on welcoming socket for contact by client
        Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
        //create input stream, attached to socket
        DataInputStream inFromClient =
                new DataInputStream(connectionSocket.getInputStream());
        //create output stream, attached to socket
        DataOutputStream outToClient =
                new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
        //read in line from socket
        clientWord = inFromClient.readUTF();
    System.out.println(clientWord);

        if(clientWord.equals("query"))
        {


            try 
            {
         // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
         FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);


         // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
         BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(fileReader);


                while((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) 
                {
             System.out.println(line);
             bytNumber = line.getBytes().length;
             holder=Integer.toString(bytNumber);
             //pr.println(bytNumber);//only printing first line not going until eof
            outToClient.writeBytes(holder);
             // line = buffer.readLine();
            // pr.flush();
                }   

         // Always close files.
         buffer.close();         
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException ex) 
            {
         System.out.println(
             "Unable to open file '" + 
             fileName + "'");                
            }
            catch(IOException ex) 
            {
         System.out.println(
             "Error reading file '" 
             + fileName + "'");                  
         // Or we could just do this: 
         // ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }// end if statement
    }

  catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
}

}
```

**Client**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
  import java.io.InputStreamReader;
  import java.net.Socket;
  import java.io.*;


  public class TcpClient {


       public static void main(String[] args) {
         String temp;
         String displayBytes;
        try
        {
        //create input stream
        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        //create client socket, connect to server
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost",5555);
        //create output stream attached to socket
        DataOutputStream outToServer =
                new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());



        System.out.print("Command : ");

        //create input stream attached to socket
        DataInputStream inFromServer = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

        temp = inFromUser.readLine();

        //send line to server
        //outToServer.writeBytes(temp);
        outToServer.writeUTF(temp);
        outToServer.flush();


       //read line from server
        //displayBytes = inFromServer.readLine();

        while((displayBytes = inFromServer.readUTF()) != null)
        {
        System.out.print(displayBytes);
        }
        //clientSocket.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
}
```